# Babel + Python function definition with for loop causes IndentationError

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, indentation, python

I am using orgmode and Babel to run Python source code blocks.
I noticed that if I define a function that returns a value, and if this function has a for loop inside it, then evaluating it with Babel leads to an `IdentationError: unexpected indent`.

For example, in org-mode write the following:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results silent :session pysession
  def foo():
      for _ in range(1):
          pass
      return 1

  print(foo())
#+END_SRC
```

Then calling `C-c C-c` sends the code to the `pysession` buffer running the Python session, and it results in the error `IdentationError: unexpected indent`.

However, if we remove the for loop from the function definition, then things just work (prints 1):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results silent :session pysession
  def foo():
      return 1

  print(foo())
#+END_SRC
```

**Question**: How to fix this behavior so that I can define functions with loops and have them work with babel?

**Edit 1:** The `print` can be removed from the code and the error still arises. The `:results silent` option is necessary since I do not want results in my org-file.

**Edit 2:** I noticed that when `:results silent` is selected and `C-c C-c`, it appears that Babel is sending the code line by line to the session, but when the line that contains the `pass` is send, Babel for some reason sends another `RET`, which makes the python REPL finish defining the function `foo` without any return statement. Then, when the line containing `return 1` is sent, it is evaluated out of the scope of the function and causes the indentation error!!!

At [this doc page](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html) it says:

> Session mode in python is slightly different from non-session mode ... blank lines are special: they indicate the end of an indented block

But in this case it is not working at all: there is no line between `pass` and `return 1`, but Babel is treating as if there was, since it is thinking the indented block is ended after `pass`. 
It seems there is some bug with the backend.

When we use `:results output`, Babel actually saves the contents of the code block as is in a temporary file. It then reads the file and evaluates it in Python with `exec`. Since Python gets the entire code at once it works.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: An odd thing is that if `:results silent` is changed to `:results output` or `:results value`, the indentation error is not thrown.

Comment: @Win I just tested it here and it does work. Unfortunately I have no idea how the code is sent to the python interpreter under the hood.

Comment: I just tried your code block and it seems that if you remove the 2 spaces at the beginning of each code line it works without throwing an indentation error, with `:results output` or with `:results silent`.

Comment: @Lgen even by removing the 2 spaces at the beginning (keeping the for loop in and :results silent) I still get the error.

Comment: Do you have some other errors/messages in ```pysession``` buffer? Seems that the variable ```_``` is not generated, and in your case is shadowed by the ```IndentationError:``` - in my configuration, when using ```:results silent``` I get the message ```NameError: '_' is not defined```.

Answer (score 0):

For best results and features edit code blocks by running in a dedicated buffer using `org-edit-special`.

With pointer in the code block type <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>  `org-edit-src-code` that will open in your case a python buffer with your hooks, the configured indentations and all.

Use <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> to return to the org file.

from gnu.org:

> C-c ' for editing the current code block. It opens a new major-mode edit buffer containing the body of the ‘src’ code block, ready for any edits. C-c ' again to close the buffer and return to the Org buffer.
>
> C-x C-s saves the buffer and updates the contents of the Org buffer.
>
> Set org-edit-src-auto-save-idle-delay to save the base buffer after a certain idle delay time.
>
> Set org-edit-src-turn-on-auto-save to auto-save this buffer into a separate file using auto-save-mode.
>
> C-c ' to close the major-mode buffer and return back to the Org buffer.
>
> While editing the source code in the major-mode, the org-src-mode minor mode remains active. It provides these customization variables as described below. For even more variables, look in the customization group org-edit-structure.

For more details and how to configure specifically [editing-source-code](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Editing-source-code.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately that's what I already do to edit source-code blocks and the problem still happens. I also tried changing the default indentation but it also leads to the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error. On my system, the answer is `nil`. But if you change the header to `:results output :session pyssesion` the result of evaluating is OK. See [this](https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-evaluation.html) for further explanations.

[image]

Of coarse, some other configurations/settings may be needed if the error will be the same.

Comment: The issue is that I do not want results on my org file. For example, if I just define the `foo` function without the print command, then I still get the same error.

Comment: `:results silent` is working for me. To be clear, I'm using the same block as this answer with `:results silent`. I'm on emacs 27.1 org version 9.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% that the issue you have is the same one I did, but I solved it with:

`(setq org-src-preserve-indentation t)`